# domain driven design , entity calls repository to validate related resource

Tags: php, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement DDD in php. I have an entity called message that has related fromFieldId. I want to validate that this fromField exists in database when it is set on message, I do not want to burden caller with this validation as it happens in many places in my code. However from what I understand in DDD entity should not call repositories? How would I handle this in DDD?

I want something like this:

```
class MessageEntity{

     public function setFromFieldId($fromFieldId){
         if(!$this->fromFieldRepository->isExists($fromFieldId)){
              // throw some exception
         }
         $this->fromFieldId = $fromFieldId;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a `DomainService` in terms of DDD.

From Eric Evans Domain-Driven Design:

> When a significant process or transformation in the domain is not a natural responsibility of an ENTITY or VALUE OBJECT, add an operation to the model as standalone interface declared as a SERVICE. Define the interface in terms of the language of the model and make sure the operation name is part of the UBIQUITOUS LANGUAGE. Make the SERVICE stateless.

In your case, if setting a field only once is a proper concept in your ubiquitous language, then an approach could be:

```
class SettingFieldOnceService
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(Repository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function setFieldInEntity($field, $entity)
    {
        if ($anotherEntity = $this->repository->findByField($field)) {
            throw new DomainException("...");
    }

        $entity->setField($field);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand , but it looks to me like an overkill. I need a seperate class ( service ) to just set attribute on other class ( entity ). What I do not understand it's why entity could not talk to repository directly? I understand that I should not pollute entity with infrastructe details ( eg. mysql queries ) , however if infrastructure is hidden behind well difened interface of repository then I do not see anything wrong with entity talking to that interface. Same thing goes for services , why entity could not call some service directly when it needs it ?

Comment: Repository saves or reconstitutes AggregateRoot (cluster of VO and entities where the root class is an Entity). AggregateRoot purpose is perform business logic preserving its invariants. So, if setting a field you need two entities,  maybe they belong to the same AR or you can use a DomainService that fetch those two entities an make the business logic to set that field. DDD depend on your domain, and it's  commonly used for complex domain. Maybe different approach such us ActionRecord or TableGateway fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply load the FromField AR from a repository and pass the entire instance to the Message AR, but only hold onto the id.

Pseudo-code:

```
MessageApplicationService {
    setFromFieldId(messageId, fromFieldId) {
        fromField = fromFieldRepository.findById(fromFieldId);

        //You could have a null check for fromField here
        //or call a method that throws automatically
        //e.g. findExistingById(). You could also prevent
        //null from being passed in message.setFromField

        message = messageRepository.findById(messageId);
        message.setFromField(fromField); //only holds onto the id
    }
}
```